# Google Map won't load - blank screen modification from tutorial

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have read many posts about peoples google maps producing a blank page, but after trying multiple solutions I am at a loss.

Here is my code below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Go Catch Em All Bakewell!</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKeyIsHere"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function customIcon(type) {
    return "http://moneyontheside.co.uk/icons/" + type + ".png";
}

function load() {
    alert("load");
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.213613, -1.673780),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("createXML.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var pokeid = markers[i].getAttribute("PokeID");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + PokeID;
      var icon = customIcon(type);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>

</head>
```

Any help is appreciated with this as I am struggling to debug so will more than likely have to start over.

To make the question a little more applicable to the wider audience, perhaps you could suggest where I might start with debugging? As you can see I tried to see what was going on by entering "alert()" but never got any popups.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a PHP file? You are performing GET requests but is this really necessary? I recommend you give Google Polymer a try. With it you could do:

```
<link rel="import" href="components/google-map/google-map.html">

<google-map latitude="53.213613" longitude="-1.673780"></google-map>
```

[Here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map) is the documentation of that element. I know this is not the approach you are looking for, but is easier to configure and customize. Basically Polymer is syntactic sugar over Web Components, a new set of technologies that allows creating custom elements, encapsulating styles and importing HTML files into other HTML files. I think Polymer's approach is in general modern and simpler. Create a Plnkr with Polymer set and share it here, you'll see you will like it.

Comment: The PHP file creates an XML of a load of data in my MySQL database. The reason I used the approach that I used is because it was the approach recommended by google on their tutorial. Do you think I am taking the wrong approach with this?

Comment: Oh, I see... you are using a database. I think Polymer has a method for that, check the documentation.